# How to have different icon button in action bar swipe tab?

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar, swipe

I have 4 `swipe tab` in my app. I have successfully to create a home icon on `action bar`. Now I wanted to have a pen icon beside the home icon when comes to work details tab. How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

[Swipe Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alrvb.png)

**TabsFragmentAdapter**

```
public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(index == 0) {

            Fragment fragment=new EditInformation();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;

        }
        if(index == 1) {
            Fragment fragment = new Edit_WorkForce();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        if(index == 2) {
            Fragment fragment = new Edit_WorkDetails();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        if(index == 3) {
            Fragment fragment = new Edit_Staff_Benefit_ListView();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ID", Edit.ID);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return fragment;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class ActivityB extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter tabsAdapter;
    private String[] item = new String[]{"Information","Work Force","Work Details","Staff Benefit"};
    private String id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
//        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(item[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tab_1_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.homePage:  // create homePage icon here ?
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**tab_1_menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:icon="@mipmap/home"
    android:id="@+id/homePage"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Tab"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Should I add the icon in **Edit_WorkDetails** `fragment` or inside **Activity B** ?

Comment: Beside home icon or replace home icon?

Comment: You should implement option menu in Edit_WorkDetails fragment to show option specific to it.

Comment: @Harry can give me some hints ?

Comment: Implement onCreateOptionMenu in each fragment. Different menu for Edit_WorkDetails fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the pen icon with `visible=false` in your menu.

Then, create a global `MenuItem` variable.

```
MenuItem mPenIcon;
```

and in `onPrepareOptionMenu` method

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    mPenIcon = menu.findItem(R.id.penicon); 
    return true;
}
```

when the tab you want the pen icon to appear is selected,

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
if(tab.getPosition()==1)//Replace 1 with your tab position
pen.setVisible(true);
}
```

when the tab is unselected,

```
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(tab.getPosition()==1)//Replace 1 with your tab position
pen.setVisible(false);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Edited

The first method I posted isn't the actual way of implementing that.

Here's the actual method.

Put `hasOptioinMenu(true)` in `onCreateView` of `Edit_WorkFragment`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                 @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//other codes    
setHasOptionMenu(true);
//other codes
}
```

and create menu for that fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_work, menu);
//You should create new menu for Edit_work fragment with both home and pen icons
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}  
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
}
```

Comment: menu mean Activity B ? Between,  need to create  `onPrepareOptionsMenu` ?

Comment: Yes. In you activity B.

Comment: penicon cannot resolved. Where should I put the image pen icon ? I put the homePage icon in tab_1_menu. mPenIcon in another menu ?

Comment: Should be setHasOptionsMenu

Answer (score 1):

As I got your point, you want to show specific menu option for specific fragment only.
Here I have one solution for you.

1.Add your menu item in menu xml file ex. *action_edit*

2.Add this in onCreateView() method of each fragment.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

3.Than override onPrepareOptionsMenu() in each fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_edit);
    if(item != null) {
      item.setVisible(true);
      //in fragment where you want to hide this menu item
      //item.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you :)