# Make Tabbed Layout with Custom ActionBar?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, tabbed

I am trying to make custom profile page , `Tabbed layout is embed within ActionBar` , and Tabs can change both with sliding and click on other tab.

I just started playing with ActionBar , and didn't understood what are major differences between Sherlock / simple ActionBar.

Here is what i am trying to make right now:

[image: image custom profile design]

Any Help in any form appreciated , There is no similar Github lib or helper code at net/SO , so i can't figure out how i should get started

Comment: You may refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668651/how-to-have-different-icon-button-in-action-bar-swipe-tab)

Comment: care to comment down voter ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `TabLayout` along with a `ViewPager`. These are standard controls. Google it or see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) for an example of how to use it. ActionBarSherlock isn't used anymore. Instead we use a Toolbar.